# Update SQL column with SELECT statement data

Tags: sqlite

I am currently working with DB Browser and I have a problem with updating columns.
I have a table which contains two columns: one is filled with strings and the other one is completely empty.

I have trimmed these strings with rtrim():

```
SELECT rtrim(column1, 'e') FROM table1
```

Now I want to place these trimmed strings into the empty column:

```
UPDATE table1 SET column2 = (SELECT rtrim(column1, 'e') FROM table1)
```

But now it fills the empty column with only the first trimmed string of column1, because it won't see the SELECT statement as a column, but as a string.
I also tried:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (column2) SELECT rtrim(column1, 'e') FROM table1
```

But this just doubles the amount of rows, as column2 is not 'empty', but filled with null.

I want to get something like

```
| column1 | column2 |
---------------------
|  apple  |  appl   |
|  orange |  orang  |
|  grape  |  grap   |
```

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: `UPDATE table1 SET column2 = rtrim(column1, 'e');`

Comment: @Lashane It worked, Thanks! Didn't expect the answer to be so simple

Comment: @Lashane Would you like to create an answer? I like Q/A pairs better than Q/comment pairs.